# rails 3: easiest way to load a large seed list (20,000 single words) into a table (using rake seed) on a Heroku app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my local dev machine I have a word list, one word per line, 20,000 words that I need to load into a new table I'll call Wordlist.

And I need to create that exact same table on several Heroku apps as well, which dont have local file storage.

the table schema is just id:integer and word:string

I've read numerous articles about using seed.rb ... but don't quite see how to make that work with a word list in a file on my dev machine, loading the list into a table on my local dev machine AND on remote Heroku app instances.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very similar to @chris I found this discussion of doing it in seed.rb and running rake db:seed .. this simply grabs the wordlist in simple one-per-line text format from an internet url. ran this successfully on a 10k word list.

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data

here's our code in seed.rb:

```
require 'open-uri'

thefile = "http://www.example.com/wordlist.txt"
puts "deleting old words"
Wordlist.delete_all
x = 0
puts "opening '#{thefile}"
  open(thefile) do |words|
    puts "file opened"
    words.read.each_line do |aword|  
      puts "read: #{aword}"
      nextword = aword.chomp
      x = x+1
      puts "putting #{x} -> #{nextword}"
      Wordlist.create!(:txt => nextword, :x => x)  
    end  
  end
```

Answer (score 6):

I would take that word list and stick in into a csv, with one word on each line. That should take you a 2 minutes. Then use the FasterCSV gem to iterate through that csv you have saved in /lib/data. You can stick it into /db/seeds.rb.

seeds.rb

```
FasterCSV.foreach("#{RAILS_ROOT}/lib/data/words.csv", :headers => :first_row) do |row|
  Word.create_by_name(row[0])
end
```

Run your rake db:seed and that's it. BTW the :headers => :first_row just means skip the first row if you have like a title on top. If you don't just leave that part out.

For remote file:

```
require 'open-uri'
FasterCSV.foreach(open("http://remotehost.com/words.csv"), :headers => :first_row) do |row|
  Word.create_by_name(row[0])
end
```

Comment: @nolie was thinking more that you would run it on development and run it on heroku. Then you won't need to override the db. The csv file will be part of the project so you can just do 'heroku rake db:seed' and it will do the same on remote staging/production environment as it does on staging with overwriting any other tables.

Comment: That was helpful... upvoted answer... after reading your answer found a slight variation that grabs file from a url which solves our Heroku issue very simply.

Comment: Ah I see. I'll include the remote file way in my answer. Maybe get me a checkmark. lol. Glad to help

Comment: FYI, FasterCSV is now deprecated as of 1.9. You'll get a warning if you try using it. Just replace ```FasterCSV``` with ```CSV```

Comment: Note in Rails 3+ use Rails.root instead of #{RAILS_ROOT}

Answer (score 2):

Chris's answer will get the data in you local database.   Once its there, heroku already has a built in solution for transfering data to your heroku apps.  The command is

```
heroku db:push
```

More is explained here http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/taps

Comment: Thanks, though from the docs I think that only does the whole dbase which we dont want to do... we're adding a table to an existing production dbase.

Comment: Yes, it does overwite the existing database.  If its a production db..    I dunno... hope you've built an api =P

Comment: In all seriousness, you probably could build small simple Rack/Sinatra app with one POST action.  When you post your data to the endpoint, it could insert the element into your production DB.  Then on the client side (you)  you take Chris's script, loop through the data, and have each iteration HTTP post to your endpoint..  that would actually work.  You can mount the rack app into your rails application using routes

Comment: Third option, is that you could just load the data directly from the migration.  Upoload the data file in the git push, have the migration open it and run through the file, and load the data as it migrates the tables